# How to define EventHub output?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function (using the new precompiled function support in VS 2017 Preview) working for an input trigger from Event Hub like this:

```
[FunctionName("ProcessSensorDataFromDevices")]
public static void Run(
    [EventHubTrigger("sensordata-ingest", Connection = "SensorDataEventHubConnection")]string sensorDataEventHubMessage,
    [EventHub("rdx-ingest", Connection = "RdxDataEventHubConnection")]out string rdxEventHubMessage,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    SensorData sensorData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SensorData>(sensorDataEventHubMessage);

    // Push the sensor data to the RDX Event Hub
    rdxEventHubMessage = sensorDataEventHubMessage;

    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {sensorDataEventHubMessage}");
}
```

I thought the output was supposed to be defined similar to the input, but there seems to be some other tricks required.

I get no compile-time errors, but I get this error when trying to run my function in the debugger:

```
[6/9/2017 9:44:37 PM] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
[6/9/2017 9:44:37 PM] Job host started
[6/9/2017 9:44:37 PM] The following 1 functions are in error:
[6/9/2017 9:44:37 PM] ProcessSensorDataFromDevices: Value cannot be null.
[6/9/2017 9:44:37 PM] Parameter name: eventHubName.
```

If I remove the two lines of code dealing with the rdxEventHubMessage, then everything works fine.

What is required to get the EventHub output properly defined?

Comment: Your code looks good. I guess you get a null issue in deserialization/processing.

Comment: No, my code was never invoked. It was a bug in the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions Nuget package. Updating it to the 1.0.0-alpha6 version (release on Friday, June 9, 2017) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions Nuget package. Updating it to the 1.0.0-alpha6 version (release on Friday, June 9, 2017) fixed the issue.